# Блокируется свойство "background"

Tags: html, css, css3, background

В браузерах Chrome и Firefox перестали отображаться логотип и другие иконки - блокируется свойство "background". В других браузерах все нормально отображается. Кэш и куки чистил. В чем может быть проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В собственных стилях браузера, попробуй !important

Comment: еще у тебя неправильно свойства background написаны (желтый треугольник)

Comment: в файере и хроме блочится, а других - а в каких других ?

Comment: @MaximLensky в Опера, Яндекс, Safari и в мобильных все нормально

Comment: тем вивер есть ?

Comment: @VitaliyScherban да, спасибо, нужно было вынести отдельно "background-size: cover", в одну строчку почему-то не работает

Comment: @MaximLensky спасибо, сделал